# Can the card-boxes that contain toothpaste tubes be recycled?

Tags: recycling

I looked everywhere on the box itself but no notice at all. They usually have colourful prints on them and seem plastic-coated to give a "shiny" effect, but on the other hand they don't look very different from cereal boxes or cigarettes packs, so I'm not sure.

Comment: A photo might help...

Answer (score 1):

> You can leave tape and labels on the box

You should check with your local recycling scheme [like this one](https://wasteindustries.com/commercial/recycling/cardboard.aspx).

Alternatively you may take it to your local recycling centre.